# Javascript dom child of a div containing a link

Tags: javascript, dom, parent, children

I am puzzled by the following code and results generated by changing an example on www.w3schools.com. Specifically when a link is a child of some parent I do not understand why parent.children returns the value of `href` when the element is an `<a>` tag?

```html
​<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com/my.jpg"></a>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var c = document.body.children;
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
txt = txt + c[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

The above code delivers the following result, the first one being the one I did not anticipate.

```
http://www.example.com/my.jpg           
[object HTMLButtonElement]
[object HTMLParagraphElement]
[object HTMLScriptElement]
```

So rather than list the `<a>` tag as an object, the value of the href attribute is given instead.

I am working on an implementation of the blueimp gallery https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery. The user selects a thumbnail and a carousel light box pops up initialised to the corresponding high resolution photo. I am working on an iphone specific issue and learning the code as I am going along.

Comment: Object + Object forces js engine to cast each to string. An `<a>` may have slightly different internal `toString()` method. Concatenating objects is not a proper practice and certinaly not a way to generate html strings

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Methods:

> [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/toString)
>
> Returns a [`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) containing the whole URL. It is a synonym for [`URLUtils.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/href), though it can't be used to modify the value.

In other words, when you convert an anchor element to a string, you get the contents of the `href` attribute.

---

By the way, this feature (`a` elements stringify as their `href` value, not `[object HTMLSomethingElement]`) has been used to bypass security checks:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1225&desc=6 *LastPass: global properties can be modified across isolated worlds, allowing remote code execution*

Comment: Thankyou for the replies, that clears it up. As far as I can make out the original code is indeed relying on this behaviour to string compare so as to identify which high res image corresponds with which thumbnail and so to initialise the carousel when it pops up to the correct choice of initial image. I experienced issues on iphone where events seem sometimes to be registered on the container div of an < a > tag containing the thumbnail. I needed to persuade the code to hunt one level down the node tree but was unsure about the apparent need to unpackage the href.

Answer (score 0):

You might want this, to print html tags of all children.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com/my.jpg"></a>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var c = document.body.children;
        var txt = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            txt = txt + c[i].outerHTML + "<br>";
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = txt;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when `txt = txt + c[i] + "<br>";` is run `c[i](<a>,< button/>, ...)` node is converted to its string representation and displayed

`<a>` tag's string representation is "http://www.example.com/my.jpg"
`< button/>` tag's string representation is [object HTMLButtonElement]
...